# Borrar registro anterior

Tags: javascript

Cuando realizo un registro se agrega pero cuando voy a agregar otro registro trae los datos anteriores registrados.

```
<form action="" id="form1" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega nueva persona</h4>
                    <div id="divMensajeEdicion"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input style="display:none" type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form- 
        control input-sm"
                        readonly>
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control 
             input-sm">
                    <label>Apellido</label>
                    <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" class="form- 
             control input-sm">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control 
             input-sm">
                    <label>Telefono</label>
                    <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="form- 
             control input-sm">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a Id="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
                    <a id="btn_guardar" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:fn_tab1_guardar_submit();">Agregar</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**js**

```
function fn_tab1_guardar_submit() //agregar
{
    var formid = "form1";
    if (!utils_validateInputs(formid, "#divMensajeEdicion")) return;
    var arrObj;
    arrObj = utils_getInputs_arrayObj(formid);
    utils_Ajax('2_Model/persona_service.php', 'add', arrObj,
        '#divMensajeEdicion', fn_tab1_guardar_submit_response, formid, 2000, 5000);

}

function fn_tab1_guardar_submit_response(objData, formid) {
    fn_pintar_Persona(objData.datos);

}
$(function () {

    $(".custom-close").on('click', function () {
        $('#modalNuevo').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Puedes poner algo más de codigo? Por ejemplo la funcion fn_tab1_guardar_submit para así ver lo que realmente hace, porque con solo html no podemos ayudate mucho.

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue

Comment: Tu codigo parece estar bien. Comprueba como estas obteniendo el ultimo registro de tu api.